# Form Button with custom image and text

Tags: html, css, image, button

A form button has a 170x60 image for the non-pressed and pressed states. What I can't seem to do is get There to be text in the button. I really want to avoid having to edit the image and write text to it directly. Right now I'm using:

```
<input type="image" src="img/button_normal.png"
 width="175" height="60" onmousedown="this.src='img/button_pressed2.png'"
 onmouseup="this.src='img/button_normal.png'">
```

I figured that it is impossible to make this work with text on top of it (as far as I have tried). So then I tried using `<button>` but I couldn't get it to work either.

I have been able to put text over the image above, but where the text is, the button is unclickable, which doesn't work.

What is a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So why not just edit the background image on a regular button?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="picker/js/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- some time later -->
<input type="button" src="img/button_normal.png" 
width="175" height="60" value="Some Text"
onmousedown="$(this).css({'background-image': 'img/button_pressed2.png'});" 
onmouseup="$(this).css({'background-image': 'img/button_normal.png'});">
```

That should give you the ability to put an image into a button with some text overlaid.

Comment: <facepalm /> Forgot to mention, set the value property of the input to whatever text you want to show. Fixed above.

Comment: Doing that just made a normal button with the value text :/

Comment: You could use CSS for this. `.mybutton { background-image: url('normal') } .mybutton:active { background-image: url('pressed.png') }`

Answer (score 6):

The `<input type="image">` is meant to have sort of an image map as button. When submitted, it sends a `name.x` and `name.y` parameter to the server side which denotes the exact location where the client has pressed on the image map.

You obviously don't want to have that. You just want to have a button with a **background** image. For that you normally use the CSS `background-image` property for (or, more conveniently, the `background` property).

Basic example:

```
.mybutton {
    background-image: url('normal.png');
    width: 175px;
    height: 60px;
}
.mybutton.pressed {
    background-image: url('pressed.png');
}
```

with the normal button as follows:

```
<input 
    type="submit"
    class="mybutton" 
    value=""
    onmousedown="this.className+=' pressed'"
    onmouseup="this.className=this.className.replace(' pressed', '')"
>
```

**Edit**: for downvoters or JS/jQuery nitpickers: IE lte 7 does **not** support the `:hover` nor `:active` pseudoselectors on other elements than the `a` element. The above solution is crossbrowser compatible.

Comment: The javascript in this is superfluous. If you just make the second CSS class .mybutton:active, it has the same effect but without requiring Javascript.

Comment: Why are you downvoting for a crossbrowser compatible solution? IE lte 7 doesn't support those pseudoselectors.

Comment: Hm I forgot about that. There are better solutions than using Javascript like this though: http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html

Comment: Brendan, that's **also** a Javascript solution. It is only a bit more advanced so that it get applied on all elements automagically.

Comment: Look, you can even see the source here: http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/htc/csshover2.htc

Comment: I don't think IE likes having a background image for buttons. Tested in Opera, Chrome, FF, and IE.
IE was the only one with problems.

Comment: I know it is, but it only relies on Javascript on the one browser that can't do it without it. Mine works in everything except IE6 whether or not Javascript is enabled (and it's easier to work with too, since once the script it set up, you can just write normal CSS and it will work).

Answer (score 5):

Why not just use css and a "submit" type?

```
<input type="submit" class="myButton" value="Label goes here" />
```

Then in your CSS:

```
input.myButton{
     background-image: url('img/button_normal.png');
     border-style:none;
}
input.myButton:hover{
    background-image: url('img/button_pressed2.png');
}
input.myButton:active{
    background-image: url('img/button_normal.png');
}
```

This will work just as well with "button" type, and has an advantage over Javascript versions because Javascript doesn't have to be enabled.

To make this work properly in IE, you can use [this script](http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html) to make IE behave itself :)

Comment: That doesn't display the image at all. Just a normal looking button with my value inside of it.

Comment: What browser are you using? I tested it in Firefox and Epiphany (webkit-based). I don't have IE :-\

Comment: Not crossbrowser compatible. IE lte 7 doesn't support those pseudoselectors.

Comment: I updated it with a link to a script that makes IE work correctly.